# WPF DataTrigger won't monitor changes

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I created a custom UserControl. It has a custom Dependency Property. A style has a Data Trigger using that property. When the form loads ExpectsFunction.get() is called twice. Then I externally set ExpectsFunction to true. If I put a breakpoint in the setter, I see that SetValue is called properly, and the property ExpectsFunction becomes 'true'. However, the DataTrigger doesn't seem to react to the change. Do I need to implement some additional event, or implement INotifyPropertyChanged and manually trigger PropertyChanged from the callback of the DependencyProperty? I thought the DataTrigger would subscribe to the DependencyProperty, but it doesn't seem to be the case :/

```
public partial class MatlabScriptSettings : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpectsFunctionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ExpectsFunctionProperty", typeof(bool), typeof(MatlabScriptSettings), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool ExpectsFunction
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ExpectsFunctionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ExpectsFunctionProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="PlatformManager.UI.Configuration.MatlabScriptSettings"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="350"
             x:Name="_this">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ArgumentsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ExpectsFunction}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ExpectsFunction}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

...

<TextBox Name="ScriptArguments" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=ScriptArguments}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ArgumentsStyle}" />

...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy (after wasting 4 hours :/)... the string of the property name must not contain *Property*.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpectsFunctionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ExpectsFunction", typeof(bool), typeof(MatlabScriptSettings), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```